# Verifying Detached PKCS7 signature on iOS: Verify error:unsupported certificate purpose

Tags: ios, objective-c, openssl

Im trying to verify a PKCS7 signature came from an API endpoint using the following code as stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html)

```
    NSURL *appleRootURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"AppleIncRootCertificate" withExtension:@"cer"];

    NSData *appleRootData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:appleRootURL];


    // Create a memory buffer to extract the PKCS #7 container

    BIO *receiptBIO ;
    receiptBIO = BIO_new_mem_buf((void *)[receiptData bytes], (int)[receiptData length]);

    BIO *dataBIO;
    dataBIO = BIO_new_mem_buf((__bridge void *)base64Encoded, (int)[base64Encoded length]);

    BIO *b_out;

    BIO *appleRootBIO;
    appleRootBIO = BIO_new_mem_buf((void *)[appleRootData bytes], (int)[appleRootData length]);


    PKCS7 *receiptPKCS7 = d2i_PKCS7_bio(receiptBIO, NULL);

    X509 *appleRootX509 = d2i_X509_bio(appleRootBIO, NULL);
    X509_STORE *store = X509_STORE_new();
    X509_STORE_add_cert(store, appleRootX509);

    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    int result = PKCS7_verify(receiptPKCS7, NULL, store, receiptBIO, b_out, 0);

    if (result != 1) {
        // Validation fails
        NSLog(@"result is %d", result);
    }
```

However, after running it to a device I am getting an OPENSSL error:

1010506260:error:21075075:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:certificate verify error:pk7_smime.c:342:Verify error:unsupported certificate purpose

Where did I go wrong? :-(

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is super old, but we recently experienced and solved the exact same problem.

Try passing `PKCS7_NOVERIFY` as the last argument to `PKCS7_verify()`, to skip chain verification on the signer cert. You (like we did, doing custom detached signature tomfoolery) probably have a signer cert that doesn't pass chain verification in this particular setup.